# What does "+ abhängiges Substantiv" paired with "in abgeblasster Bedeutung" in the dictionary mean?

Tags: verb-usage, terminology

I was reading DWDS's [definition of "liefern"](https://www.dwds.de/wb/liefern) (and later ["geben"](https://www.dwds.de/wb/geben)) and came across this:

> ⟨liefern + abhängiges Substantiv⟩in abgeblasster Bedeutung; dient zur Umschreibung eines Verbalbegriffes

> Beispiele:

> für etw. einen Beweis liefern (= etw. beweisen)
> das Ereignis lieferte für einige Tage genug Gesprächsstoff (= das Ereignis gab, bot für einige Tage genug Gesprächsstoff)

> die Gegner lieferten sich eine Schlacht, ein Treffen (= kämpften miteinander)

In particular, I'm trying to understand what this is saying about a usage of "liefern" plus a "dependent noun", but what exactly is this? What sets this apart as a usage of "liefern" from other usages (deliver/supply)? What does "in abgeblasster Bedeutung" mean? "In pale/faded meaning"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries sometimes use outdated or curious terminology. *Umschreibung eines Verbalbegriffes* is what many textbooks nowadays call *Nomen-Verb-Verbindungen*. Googling this term, you will get many lists of combinations of nouns with verbs, such as the following (note that these combinations often include prepositions, which makes the term *Nomen-Verb-Verbindungen* a misnomer).

- zum Abschluss bringen
- in Brand setzen *(anzünden)*
- eine Frage stellen
- zur Kenntnis nehmen
- …

Looking at these combinations, it is the noun that carries most of the meaning, with the verb only contributing grammatical and aspectual information. The verb's proper meaning is no longer felt in these combinations, which is what the dictionary calls *verblasst*. For instance, *in Brand setzen* means *anzünden*, there is no sitting involved. The same happens for *liefern* in your examples, where the meaning of *deliver* is not felt anymore.

With deverbal nouns, the combination can sometimes even be paraphrased by the underlying verb.

> Ich möchte Ihnen noch *eine **Frage** stellen*.
> = Ich möchte Sie noch etwas **fragen**.

These combinations allow for aspectual distinctions depending on the chosen verb. That is, the following examples are all about *moving*, as determined by the noun *Bewegung*, but the [aspectual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect) *(cause, happen, continue, …)* is contributed by the verb.

> in Bewegung setzen: *cause something to move*
> in Bewegung geraten: *happen to move*
> in Bewegung bleiben: *continue to move*
> in Bewegung sein: *be in a moving state*

More technical terms for the same phenomenon are [Nominalisierungsverb und Funktionsverb](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/514).

Comment: Thank you. Sounds like this is not a meaning I need to learn so much as be aware of, that I will encounter liefern used with no semantic meaning, in pairing with various nouns that bear the semantic weight.